# Does there exist a dipole field on $S^2$ differing by at most a minus sign between antipodal points?

Tags: differential-topology

Consider the two-sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.  By a *dipole field* on $S^2$, I mean a continuous function $f \colon S^2 \to S^2$ such that (1) $x$ is perpendicular to $f(x)$ for all $x \in S^2$ (this means that $f$ is a continuous *tangent vector field* on $S^2$), and (2) $f$ vanishes at exactly one point.

Question:  Does there exist a dipole field on $S^2$ with the property that $f(x) \in \text{span} \left\{f(-x)\right\}$ for all $x \in S^2$, except for the point $x$ where $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: Well, if that condition holds the function $f$ will vanish at **two** points at least!

Comment: Edit the question accordingly, please.

Comment: (Notice that if $f$ is continuous, if $f(x)=\pm f(-x)$ for all $x$ except at most one, then it holds for all $x$, so your "fix" does not fix the question)

Comment: Oh, you know, I guess I don't care about the size of the vectors either. Thanks for making that apparent.

Comment: There, I think that is the question I meant to ask.

Comment: A continuous tangent field $f$ to the sphere has to have a zero somewhere. Call it $x$. If you know that $f(-x)$ is in the span of $f(x)$, then of course $f(-x)$ is also zero, and you have two zeroes...

Comment: You are right.  I apologize, I am not thinking straight evidently.  This picture is my motivation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#mediaviewer/File:Hairy_ball_one_pole.jpg

Comment: And I think I finally have the question how I should have had it the first time...

Comment: (A note to the community: I had a comment between Mariano's first and second comments along the lines of "Indeed, that is true. Remove the condition for the point where $f$ vanishes."  Out of a bad habit, I deleted the comment after I made the edit.  I should stop doing that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work: construct a vector field om $\mathbb R^2-${$(0,0)$} with exactly one zero, and use the stereographic projection to pull it back to $\mathbb S^2$.

Maybe a good point to make here, is that the fact that the stereographic projection is a diffeomorphism allows you to pushforward vector fields; this is not always possible.

Comment: Or a tangent vector field on the projective plane $P^2$ with exactly one zero and pull it back along the covering map $S^2\to P^2$.

Comment: O.K, good idea. I think I need to add the condition that the vector field should go to $0$ as we "go to $\infty$ , in the compactification; I think this is necessary to preserve some basic properties.

Comment: Hi, user99680, why do you construct your vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ subtract the origin?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Can you guarantee that the vector field is well-defined under the projection? Don't we need it constant in the sense p(x)=p(-x)?

Comment: @DanDouglas: Hi Dan, I am using the fact that the two spaces ; $\mathbb R^2$ and $S^2-N$ ; $N$ is the north pole, are diffeomorphic under the stereographic projection , so that we can pushforward vector fields. WE cannot pushforward under any map, but we can if we have a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Do we not need that the vector field be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that when we use stereographic projection, we get a vector field on the whole sphere?

Comment: I believe you have it flipped: It is $S^2 - N$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are diffeomorphic, right?

Comment: @Dan Douglas: Yes, sorry, it is defined on all of $\mathbb R^2$; please see my edit of the above comment. A moment of disxeslya :).

Comment: What is meant by "push forward" in this context? That the inverse stereographic projection of the vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector field on $S^2 - N$?

Comment: And I do not see why the Span condition is satisfied, but perhaps I will have to just do the calculation in order to see that?

Comment: The pushforward is another name for the tangent map; (one of the )the versions of the derivative for manifolds ;it takes vector fields to vector fields.

Comment: Do you mean you want f(x)=f(-x)? If that is the case, then, yes, you need to define it on $\mathbb R^2$ so that f(x)=f(-x).

Comment: No, that is too specific.  See the statement of the question above.

Comment: I'm not sure, let me think it through.

Comment: @DanDouglas: I'm out for tonight; it is almost 4 a.m here, I will try to answer any followups after sleep.

Comment: @user99680 to pull **back** you just use the fact that the projection is a local diffeo.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: How exactly do you go from a tangent vector field $f \colon P^2 \to P^2$ to a tangent vector field $g \colon S^2 \to S^2$?  How do you "choose" what element of $S^2$ should correspond to an element of $P^2$ when there does not exist a lift from $P^2$ to $S^2$?  I am referring to your comment above.  More specifically, what exactly do you mean by "pull it back along the covering map"?

Comment: **Exercise:** If $p:M\to N$ is a covering map of manifolds and if $X$ is a tangent field on $N$ (that is, a section of $TN$) there there exists exactly one tangent field $Y$ on $M$ such that $dp(Y)=X$. Here «$Y$ is obtained by pulling back the tangent field $X$ to $M$».

Comment: (Tangent fields on $P^2$ are certainly not maps $P^2\to P^2$, by the way!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thank you again for your help on this question.  I am rather outside of my realm of mathematical familiarity (I was led to this question through some research that I am doing).  Would Guillemin and Pollack be an appropriate book for understanding the concepts at hand more deeply and clearly?

Comment: @DanDouglas. Sure. The book on smooth manifolds by Lee is currently my favorite.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I thought you were referring to pulling back by general covering maps, not that specific one, sorry. I think in general you need a smooth covering map to be able to pullback, and not just a topological covering map, but maybe when we talk about a covering amp between manifolds we assume smoothness.

Comment: Of course. If the map is not smooth then I don't think it even makes sense of talking about pull backs! My exercise above is for any smooth coverings. Since the one we have here is smooth, that's enough.